# Selenium/Firefox: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45 seconds when running tests through parallel_tests

Tags: firefox, selenium, rspec

I have seven separate spec files (they are for all intents and purposes identical, login to website, navigate to page, look for element, logout) - running them individually completes without any errors.

However, I want to be able to run all seven files simultaneously. And they MUST run locally on one single PC. I need to do this every day, so I need it to be a reliable process. I've tried several options detailed below all with the same issue.

It all stems (seemingly) from running multiple instances of the firefox webdriver.  So I suppose that's my question - is there a way to run multiple simultaneous instances of the firefox webdriver or is there a better route to this all together.

- If I manually kick off all seven rspec (or ruby files) simultaneously (select all, press enter) I end up with a ton of instances of the error "Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45 seconds"
- If I use parallel_tests gem:  parallel_rspec "file 1" "file 2" "file 3" etc the same issue occurs.

  [31mFailure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace[0m
       [31mSelenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:[0m
       [31m  unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45 seconds[0m
       [36m# ./spec_helper.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in '[0m

**Line 13 specifically is :         @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox**

- I created a batch file to launch each rspec file as an individual process.  This is the best option of the lot so far but I still end up with a few instances of the same error.

  START "MyProcess1" file1.rb
  PING 127.0.0.1 -n 10 || PING ::1 -n 10
  START "MyProcess2" file2.rb 
  PING 127.0.0.1 -n 10 || PING ::1 -n 10
  etc...
  :loop
    timeout /t 1 >nul
  tasklist /v|find "MyProcess">nul && goto :loop
  echo all tasks have finished.
- I also tried swapping the firefox webdriver for phantomjs, that totally barfed all over itself and refused to run a single thing.

All the information I've found on this problem so far have all because the user was inadvertently running multiple instances of the webdriver, I WANT to run multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to firefox display settings.

By default firefox webdriver waits for 45 seconds before timeout to launch the firefox. If firefox could not find the appropriate display this error msg will be reported to console. Try setting the display on linux (the following command resolved for me):

$/usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 &